# Typescript, toFixed. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, tofixed

```
       distanceX = ((this.frontclickedX  - originX) / originX).toFixed(2);
       distanceY = (-(this.frontclickedY - originY) / originY).toFixed(2);
       let distanceZ: number = (-(this.frontclickedY - originY) / originY).toFixed(2);
```

my browser throws an error when I calculated distanceZ:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

the first two lines work perfectly, but the third doesn't really work.
As you can see it is even exact the same calculation as distanceY. I tried to parseFloat() it first. But then it starts to complain that I can only parse a string to a float, and that I didn't provide one.

I'm quite confused at the moment, so some help or a solution would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried to simplify my code.
Made the distances private and added setters and getters.

```
private _distanceX: number;
private _distanceY: number;
private _distanceZ: number;

  get distanceZ(): number {
    return this._distanceZ;
}
set distanceZ(value: number) {
    this._distanceZ = value;
} ...
calculateBadgeDistance(): void{
        this.distanceX = (5.001).toFixed(2);
        this.distanceY = (5.001).toFixed(2);
        this.distanceZ = (5.001).toFixed(2);
}
```

Now I got the error on all 3 lines.

Comment: on which line does this occur?
This snipped should work, if the variables are all numbers

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The method `toFixed()` converts a number to a string.
You have to parse the variables to numbers:

```
let distanceZ:number = parseFloat((-(this.frontclickedY - originY) / originY).toFixed(2));
```

Alternatively, temporarily store the string and parse it later

```
let distanceZTxt:string = (-(this.frontclickedY - originY) / originY).toFixed(2);
let distanceZ:number = parseFloat(distanceZTxt);
```

Comment: This worked for me now.
But do you know why it worked for dinstanceX, distanceY but not for distanceZ?

Thanks a lot for the fix :)

Comment: Maybe you didn't define any type for `distanceY` and `distanceX` in the first place? If not, the variables will accept any data type.

Comment: I did, they are all private variables with setters and getters 
`private _distanceX: number;`
`private _distanceY: number;`
 `private _distanceZ: number;`

Comment: If they are all defined with the data type number, the error should occur on all variables unless you parse them from string to number. I see that with your updated code, you defined them as numbers, but are you sure they were numbers in your first attempt? Otherwise I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I defined them in the function like this:
`let distanceX, distanceY, distanceZ: number; `

Comment: I don't think the two first will receive a data type when you write it like that. `let distanceX:number, distanceY:number, distanceZ: number;` however will give them the number type

Comment: aha okay got it.
Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help ^^ Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can write your function like that to avoid this issue

```
get distanceZ(): number | string {
    return this._distanceZ;
 }
```

add "| string " with your function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((this.frontclickedX  - originX) / originX).toFixed(2) as any
```